# How to filter an array of objects by groupBy on key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have below algorithmic base problem and I'm trying to solve it with ES6, but I'm getting confused with `groupBy`,

```
let data = [
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 02:02:58", value: 7.0},
  {id: "1", time: "3/11/2016 02:12:32", value: 6.5},
  {id: "1", time: "3/11/2016 02:13:11", value: 7.25},
  {id: "4", time: "3/11/2016 02:13:54", value: 8.75},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 05:02:45", value: 11.0},
  {id: "4", time: "3/11/2016 06:32:42", value: 5.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 06:35:12", value: 2.0},
  {id: "1", time: "3/11/2016 06:45:01", value: 12.0},
  {id: "1", time: "3/11/2016 06:59:59", value: 11.75},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 07:01:53", value: 1.0},
  {id: "1", time: "3/11/2016 07:02:54", value: 4.5},
  {id: "3", time: "3/11/2016 07:02:54", value: 15.75},
  {id: "6", time: "3/11/2016 07:02:54", value: 14.25},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 07:03:15", value: 12.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 08:02:22", value: 3.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 09:41:50", value: 4.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 10:02:54", value: 5.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 11:05:35", value: 10.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 13:02:21", value: 6.0},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 13:02:40", value: 8.0},
  {id: "4", time: "3/11/2016 13:02:55", value: 8.0},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 13:33:34", value: 8.0},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 13:42:24", value: 8.0},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 13:47:44", value: 6.25},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 14:02:54", value: 4.25},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 14:03:04", value: 5.25},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 15:12:55", value: 6.25},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 16:02:36", value: 8.0},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 16:22:11", value: 8.5},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 17:18:19", value: 11.25},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 18:19:20", value: 9.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 23:59:59", value: 9.0}
];
```

Trying to get subset of array with the following condition:

1. Each `id` within each one hour period, only the most expensive value should be in result set.
2. If more than one object with the same `id` equals the most expensive value in a one hour period, only place the earliest one.
3. If there are more than 8 objects for an `id` in the overall array of objects, remove it.

I know how it's easily achievable in SQL with MAX on **'value'** and GroupBy on **'time'** column, but here I get confused with the JS loop. Please suggest some tricks if possible.

I was trying like below, but seems still long way to go

```
var newArr = [];
data.forEach(function (el) {
    var findIndex = newArr.findIndex(function (item) {
        return item.time === el.time;
    });
    if (findIndex === -1) {
        newArr.push(el);
    } else if (el.value > newArr[findIndex].value) {
        newArr[findIndex].value = el.value;
        newArr[findIndex].time = el.time;
    } else {
        newArr[findIndex].time = el.time;
    }
});
```

just for making it more clear output will be like that

```
[
  { id: "4",time: "3/11/2016 02:13:54",value: 8.75 },
  { id: "1", time: "3/11/2016 06:45:01",value: 12.0 },
  { id: "3",time: "3/11/2016 07:02:54",value: 15.75 },
  { id: "4", time: "3/11/2016 13:02:55", value: 8.0}
]
```

Record of id: "2" and "5" removed because it has more than 8 appearance 
I found something [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/5pjhhe/ruby_code_challenge/) but seems ruby

Comment: @Spangle just look the question I edited it .. hope you understand it what I am trying

Comment: Where in your snippet do you try to check if there are more than 8 objects with the same id?

Comment: I would recommend using libraries like moment and lodash for this.

Comment: For point #3. Removed ... based on what condition? Lowest `value` or oldest `time`?

Comment: Remove should be based on if repeat more than 8 times in array..

Comment: Not really an answer. Suppose that you don't have a list that is sorted on time, how would you differ which element that should be removed or not when you got more than 8 items? Should you remove the ones with the lowest values or the oldest ones? I suppose the latter because the list is ordered on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to
a) create date objects from the data['time']
b) sort the array in some way, using an object.
c) filter out excessive data.

Hopefully, the code explains itself. I tried to do it in a dynamic way so you can use this will all kinds of years, months, and days, because I supposed it wasn't just the hours you wanted.

`filterOutOldestIds` has a quite ugly nested for loop, but I couldn't figure out a better way, if I wanted it to be dynamic but still manageable.

```js
let data = [
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 02:02:58", value: 7.0},
  {id: "1", time: "3/11/2016 02:12:32", value: 6.5},
  {id: "1", time: "3/11/2016 02:13:11", value: 7.25},
  {id: "4", time: "3/11/2016 02:13:54", value: 8.75},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 05:02:45", value: 11.0},
  {id: "4", time: "3/11/2016 06:32:42", value: 5.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 06:35:12", value: 2.0},
  {id: "1", time: "3/11/2016 06:45:01", value: 12.0},
  {id: "1", time: "3/11/2016 06:59:59", value: 11.75},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 07:01:53", value: 1.0},
  {id: "1", time: "3/11/2016 07:02:54", value: 4.5},
  {id: "3", time: "3/11/2016 07:02:54", value: 15.75},
  {id: "6", time: "3/11/2016 07:02:54", value: 14.25},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 07:03:15", value: 12.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 08:02:22", value: 3.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 09:41:50", value: 4.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 10:02:54", value: 5.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 11:05:35", value: 10.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 13:02:21", value: 6.0},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 13:02:40", value: 8.0},
  {id: "4", time: "3/11/2016 13:02:55", value: 8.0},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 13:33:34", value: 8.0},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 13:42:24", value: 8.0},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 13:47:44", value: 6.25},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 14:02:54", value: 4.25},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 14:03:04", value: 5.25},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 15:12:55", value: 6.25},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 16:02:36", value: 8.0},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 16:22:11", value: 8.5},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 17:18:19", value: 11.25},
  {id: "5", time: "3/11/2016 18:19:20", value: 9.0},
  {id: "2", time: "3/11/2016 23:59:59", value: 9.0}
];

function filterOnMaxValue(arr) {
  let MAX_OCCURANCES = 8;
  var controlObj = {},
      sortedArr = [];   // don't really need this, but using it for added clarity
  
  arr.forEach((el) => {
    controlObj = setHighestValueBasedOnDate(el, controlObj);
  });
  
  sortedArr = filterOutOldestIds(controlObj, MAX_OCCURANCES);

  return sortedArr;
}

function setHighestValueBasedOnDate(el, controlObj) {
  let date = new Date(el.time),
      year = date.getFullYear(),
      month = date.getMonth(),
      day = date.getDay(),
      hour = date.getHours(),
      id = el.id;

  controlObj = createDefaultStructure(id, year, month, day, hour, controlObj);

  let previousEl = controlObj[id][year][month][day][hour];
  controlObj[id][year][month][day][hour] = (previousEl && previousEl.value > el.value) ? previousEl : el;

  return controlObj;
}

function createDefaultStructure(id, year, month, day, hour, controlObj) {
  controlObj[id] = controlObj[id] || {};
  controlObj[id][year] = controlObj[id][year] || {};
  controlObj[id][year][month] = controlObj[id][year][month] || {};
  controlObj[id][year][month][day] = controlObj[id][year][month][day] || {};

  return controlObj;
}

function filterOutOldestIds(controlObj, maxAllowedOccurances) {
  var sortedArr = [],
      idOccurances = {},
      idObj, yearObj, monthObj, dayObj, hourObj;

  for (id in controlObj) {
    idOccurances[id] = -1;
    idObj = controlObj[id];
    
    for (year in idObj) {
      yearObj = idObj[year];
      
      for (month in yearObj) {
        dayObj = yearObj[month];
        
        for (hour in dayObj) {
          hourObj = dayObj[hour];

          for (el in hourObj) {
            idOccurances[id]++;
            
            // this check should honestly be in every for loop, apart from 'id in controlObj'
            if (idOccurances[id] < maxAllowedOccurances) {
              sortedArr.push(hourObj[el]);   
            } else {
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return sortedArr;
}

let sortedData = filterOnMaxValue(data);
console.log(sortedData);
```

```html
<p>Trying to get subset of array with below condition</p>

<ul>
  <li>Each Id within each one hour period, only the most expensive value should be in resultset.</li>
  <li>If more than one objects from the same Id equal for the most expensive value in a one hour period, only place the earliest one.</li>
  <li>If there are more than 8 object for an Id in the overall array of objects, remove it.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your effort is really helpful, but here my problem is filtering out data for every time span given, each time span should have exactly one value that will be highest.
for example for first four record it should be 
{id: "4", time: "3/11/2016 02:13:54", value: 8.75}

Comment: OK, but now you got code to begin with, which you can modify to get what you want. :) I just wonder what happens if you have eight values of `id: 4` and another with id: 4 is the highest one for another hour. There are use cases that aren't described and handled with your three points in the original post.

Comment: It should be removed regardless highest for another hour, if count is greater than 8 it should removed first..